# Method call in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

In my Jenkins pipeline I need to call several methods based on the parameter that I get at the run time. For example, If I give the parameter as "Development", it should call the method "Developmentadaptation" similarly for other parameters as well. Below is the code which i tried where INSTANCE is the parameter for the build and if I give the parameter as qa, then it should call the method "qaadaptation"

```
                steps { 
                    script {
                    adaptcall = INSTANCE + adaptation;
                    adaptcall()
                    }

                }
```

Error Message is

```
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), take(int), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Comment: If you change your architecture such that there is only one method with a `String` input argument based off of your parameter, it will be cleaner and function as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a string variable as a method, but you can try this:

```
                steps { 
                    script {
                        "${INSTANCE}adaptation"()
                    }
                }
```